# how to show mysql data withour refresh page, click button, change etc

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I want to show my mysql data without refresh page, click button, change etc. If anyone one submit data on mysql from anywhere then I can see the his/her submitted data without refresh, change, click. data come from me automatically. I know jquery, ajax, php but I don't find any way solving this problem. If you have any idea, please, share with me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, It is not clear what the question is.. Could you share some images or elaborate more..? I see this question is already attracting -ve votes as it is unclear.

Comment: If you know jquery, ajax and php, then you should be able to do it. Start with something and we are here to help.

Comment: use ajax in simple words. whether use jQuery or javascript both will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know jQuery, AJAX and PHP, but you don't know how to change data? At least try to be creative...

First you need a PHP page that get's the database data.

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'config.php';

$json = array(
    'data'  => array()
);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `my_table`');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($json['data'], $row);
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

As you might notice, I like to transfer the data as JSON - hence the `header()` and `json_encode()` call.

If you go to that page you'll see the results from your database. Now you can call that file using jQuery AJAX. If you use an interval you can get the new data every x seconds.

```javascript
setInterval(fetchData, 10000); // get data every 10 seconds

function fetchData() {
    $.getJSON('myfile.php', function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $.each(data.data, function(index, value) {
            // do something with every row

            console.log(value.id, value.content, value.date);
        });
    });
}
```

Voila!

---

I can have huge discussions that programmers *are* creative. This is my point exactly. Knowing a language doesn't make you a good developer. If it helps you, get a piece of paper and make a flow-graph or something.

Answer (score 1):

Make a PHP file

example.php

```
// connect sql && make query

$dataArray = array();
// After you connected and prepared the query show it
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query) {
    $dataArray[] = $fetch;
}

// Put data in a json object for JS
$dataArray = json_encode($dataArray);

// Echo it
echo $dataArray;
```

And call it with jQuery or any other js lib.

```
$(this).get('example.php'), function(data) {
    alert(data); // You'll see the json object in here <<
    // Then do magic stuff with it.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need to set timer using JavaScript function setinterval(function(){}, time in millisecond). Set time to 5000 for 5 sec or as you wish so that the code runs each 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reverse Ajax or javascript function setinterval , if data come automatically best option is use Reverse Ajax